# I Pay for iTunes Match So Why Does iTunes Radio Now Have Ads (iTunes 12.0.1.26)

Tags: itunes, itunes-match, itunes-radio

I pay for iTunes Match, account is in good standing, auto-renew is turned on.

I just update to iTunes 12.0.1.26 now I have ads when using iTunes radio.  How do I get rid of them?  I've already tried [these recommendations](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6616500).

**UPDATE:** I went to *Store* -> *Update iTunes Match*, after it updated I skipped through the max (6 songs) on 4 different stations (24 total songs) and have not seen an ad yet.  Maybe that did the trick.  I was skipping through them though, not listening to them.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, and found something that worked. I skipped around 30 songs, listen to 3 on the same station (as I am writing this post) and no ads.

Devices
iPhone 5s - No commercials there
2 PCs: one with Windows 7 (64-bit) and the other Windows 8.1 (64-bit);

Problem:
I have iTunes Match and still here ads

Solution:
Enter iTunes → Store → Deauthorize this computer

After
Store → Authorize this computer
Store → Turn on iTunes match

Answer (score -2):

I don't think they have anything to do with one another. iTunes match gives you the high-quality version of any song in your library. You can then have access to these songs from any of your devices.

iTunes radio is just listening to music, online, like a radio.

Comment: They do have something to do with one another because by purchasing iTunes Match you are supposed to also get AD-free iTunes Radio as part of the deal.  From this thread (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6616500) it seems like it might just be a PC issue.  Users are saying iPads and iMacs are not getting ads, but PC users are.